# effective c++ item 31: recompilation

Tags: c++, compilation, effective-c++

I'm reading Effective C++ Item 31: Minimize compilation dependencies between files.

It says:
[image]

I made a little test with the code below:

//A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A();
    int getInt();
    int i;
};

#endif
```

//A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

A::A():i(97)
{}

int A::getInt()
{
    return 2;
}
```

//TestA.h

```
#include "A.h"
class TestA
{
public:
    TestA();
    int getInt();
    A a;
};
```

//TestA.cpp

```
#include "TestA.h"
TestA::TestA():a(A())
{}

int TestA::getInt()
{
    return a.getInt();
}
```

I have three classes like `TesetA`.

First I compile them with makefile. Then I do some changes for class `A`. For example, add some new data and member functions, change the value of `getInt()`. I recompile them.
However, I found that only A.cpp had been recompiled.

Here is my makefile:

```
ibcpp=-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

all: res.out

res.out: main.o FactoryA.o TestA.o TestB.o A.o
        g++ $(libcpp) main.o FactoryA.o TestA.o TestB.o A.o -o0 res.out

main.o: main.cpp
        g++ $(libcpp) -c main.cpp -O0 -o main.o

FactoryA.o: FactoryA.cpp
        g++ $(libcpp) -c FactoryA.cpp -O0 -o FactoryA.o

TestA.o: TestA.cpp
        g++ $(libcpp) -c TestA.cpp -O0 -o TestA.o

TestB.o:TestB.cpp
        g++ $(libcpp) -c TestB.cpp -O0 -o TestB.o

A.o: A.cpp
        g++ $(libcpp) -c A.cpp -O0 -o A.o
```

Now I'm confused. If I understand the Item 31 correctly, shouldn't all of files be recompiled?

Comment: You're right, all the .cpp files need to be recompiled. The fact that your build system, whatever it is, didn't do that is a flaw in the build system.

Comment: Compilers are pretty smart to avoid unneeded work. However, if the size of `A` changed, then at least *TestA.cpp* needs to be recompiled. The bug could be in your makefile, but we cannot see it. (Although in this simple case your compiler could actually deduce, that none of the data members are used, and `a.getInt()` doesn't require an `A` instance, so maybe it didn't have to recompile anything.)

Comment: @IInspectable    OK. If I use factory pattern, I could avoid the recompilation?

Comment: I don't know how the Factory pattern would be suited to reduce recompilation. The pImpl idiom, on the other hand, can.

Comment: The make file doesn't have any dependencies on the header files, so changing things in the headers won't trigger recompilations.

Comment: @PeteBecker So you mean we can avoid recompilations by a good makefile?

Comment: No. A makefile that omits recompilation, **although it should recompile** is generally perceived as a *bad* makefile. What good is a tool that only works sometimes? You probably simply didn't notice that a recompile was due, because your application didn't change its observable behavior. You have executed a stale programming, without noticing.

Comment: @IInspectable  So you mean my makefile is wrong? I don't understand. Because I've tried to do some changes in `A.cpp` and I could see the changes. For example, I create an object `TestA` and `cout` its `getInt()`. If I change the returned value in `A::getInt()` and remake I could see the different values.

Comment: You are applying changes, that don't expose the effects of failure to recompile. Change your class `A` to have the member `getSpecialInt()`, and remove `getInt()`. That'll likely produce a linker error.

Comment: @IInspectable  No, it still works. I did what you asked me to do and I changed `a.getInt` into `a.getSpecialInt` in the function `getInt()` of `TestA`. Then remake, I can see that `A.cpp`, 'TestA.cpp` and `main.cpp` are all recompiled and it works.

Comment: That's not what I told you to do. I asked you to change `A` (and only `A`), and leave `TestA` as is. Of course *TestA.cpp* is recompiled, if you make changes to it, so no surprise here.

Comment: @IInspectable  So Effective c++ item 31 means that we can avoid the recompilations if we use some technique such as the plmpl idiom?

Comment: @IInspectable   Also, my makefile is bad?

Comment: I don't know, what item 31 suggests as a solution. There's only the problem description replicated in your question, although the pImpl idiom is one way to break dependencies, reducing (needless) recompilation.